# EVERY Xcode project errors on every other run

Tags: compiler-errors, xcode4.6, sigabrt

So I am having a major issue. I have completely uninstalled Xcode and used terminal to perform a complete uninstall or all Xcode related files. I deleted the application and then have just reinstalled from the App Store.

Here is what is STILL happening.

Create a brand new project. Without writing any code, hit run, and the app runs perfect.

Stop the app, and hit run again, I get an error.

Hit stop and then run again, works, then stop and run again and it doesnt work. Here is what is popping up:

[image: Error]

I have no idea why it is doing this, just started today. Is there another FULL PROOF way to uninstall Xcode?

Does anyone recognize this?

I am running the latest version of Xcode.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on exceptions to see what's actually causing the error?  It can be a bit dicey whether that works with SIGABRT but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, It doesnt place any breakpoints anywhere. This exact same thing happens in a brand new single view (or any of the templates) project too without writing ANY code. I may just have to restore the entire computer

Comment: Are you still having this problem?  I bet it's your Xcode settings (which don't get deleted / reset when you re-install Xcode).  Try creating a new user account on your Macintosh and see if you have the same trouble with Xcode when building things with that new account.

Comment: I was never able to solve the problem directly, but I did get it working. I had to go to the Apple Store and have them re-install OSX from a clean partition because apparently my recovery partition just wasn't doing the job when I would reinstall OSX from scratch.